# Set different constraints for Different Size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, size-classes

I have use the storyboard to create an UI for application. I set the constraints for wCompact hAny and now I want to set different constraints for wCompact hRegular(iphone6+). For this what should I have to do. Please give me any example for this.

Comment: Can you provide any image for your UI so that i can get more idea what actually you want to do.

Comment: let consider any image of hight 100 width 300, For wCompact hAny its y value is 72 and for wCompact and hRegular I want its y value should be 120. means little bit down because If I put same y value then it not looks good. my problem is that If I change the height for one size it would also change the other size classes constraints and all.

Answer (score -1):

You just change you the size and update the constraints accordingly. This will save and be loaded according to the size.

Comment: in which size class I have to change? If I select wCompact and hRegular than how to disable the constraints of wCompact hAny constraints, and whatever changes I will do It affects only this size class not others.

Comment: this video not working for me.. how you set different different constraints without deleting previous one.

Comment: http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2014/08/working-with-size-classes-in-interface-builder/